# Can R read from a file through an ssh connection?

Tags: r, ssh

R can read files on a web server using convenient syntax such as

```
data <- read.delim("http://remoteserver.com/file.dat")
```

I wonder if there is a way to do something similar with a file on an ssh server with passwordless-ssh already in place?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can read a file using pipes like this:

```
d = read.table( pipe( 'cat data.txt' ), header = T )
```

If you wanted to read from an SSH connection, try this:

```
d = read.table( pipe( 'ssh hostname "cat data.txt"' ), header = T )
```

There's also no reason to confine this to just ssh commands, you could also do something like this:

```
d = read.table( pipe( 'cat *.txt' ) )
```

See the [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Connections) page for more information, specifically the [Connections](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Connections) section.

Comment: @james Thompson, do you need a package for ssh connection in R. I need to do same, connect to remote server with ssh and read a file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using Windows R to connect a Linux server and failed, no problem between linux servers, any idea?

Comment: Can I list files inside the connection created with pipe?