# Translate Python MySQL ssh port forwarding solution to R (dbplyr)

Tags: r, tidyverse, portforwarding, dbplyr

I'm trying to query a MySQL server through an R/Tidyverse/dbplyr workflow. My MySQL access requires configuring SSH and port forwarding.

I have this code working using python (below), but I'm struggling to get started with the SSH/port forwarding *equivalent* in R. Any pointers to solutions or equivalent R packages appreciated. thanks.

```
import pymysql
import paramiko
import pandas as pd
from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from os.path import expanduser


pkeyfilepath = '/.ssh/id_ed25519'
home = expanduser('~')
mypkey = paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file(home + pkeyfilepath)

sql_hostname = 'mycompany.com'
sql_username = 'me'
sql_password = '***'
sql_main_database = 'my_db'
sql_port = 3306
ssh_host = 'jumphost.mycompany.com'
ssh_user = 'me'
ssh_port = 22

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
                           passwd=sql_password, db=sql_main_database,
                           port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
    query = '''SELECT VERSION();'''
    data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    print(data)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Read this [Accessing MySQL through R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/05/accessing-mysql-through-r/)

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar this information, it’s the ssh port forwarding that I’m struggling with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [how do you connect to a remote server with ssh in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347450/how-do-you-connect-to-a-remote-server-with-ssh-in-r)

Comment: Googling R can be problematic. When I need to find something for R, I tend to search for `cran <topic>`, where CRAN refers to the repository of R packages. In this case, [`cran ssh`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+ssh) suggests (high on _my_ list, at least) the [`ssh`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh/index.html) package. That page lists the package url as https://docs.ropensci.org/ssh/, which includes a section on how to [Create a Tunnel](https://docs.ropensci.org/ssh/#create-a-tunnel).

Comment: Unfortunately, this call *blocks* as long as the tunnel is active, meaning you'd need to start it in another R process, using any number of methods including a separate R instance, the `callr::r_bg` function, or perhaps the `processx` package. Also, this function only forwards the port *once*, which may or may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do ssh port forwarding for R. In no particular order:

1. I forward it externally to R. All of my work is remote, and for one particular client I need access to various instances of SQL Server, Redis, MongoDB, remote filesystems, and a tunnel-hop to another network only accessible from the ssh bastion host. I tend to do work in more than R, so it's important to me that I generalize this. It is not for everybody or every task.

   For this, I used a mismash of [`autossh`](https://github.com/jazzl0ver/autossh) and my ssh-agent (in KeePass/KeeAgent).
2. The `ssh` package does have a function to [Create a Tunnel](https://docs.ropensci.org/ssh/#create-a-tunnel). The premise is that you have already created a "session" to which you can add a forwarding rule(s). When using `ssh::ssh_tunnel`, it is *blocking*, meaning you cannot use it in the same R process and continue to work. Demo:

   ```r
   # R session 1
   sess <- ssh::ssh_connect("user@remote")
   # insert passphrase
   ssh::ssh_tunnel(sess, 21433, "otherremote:1433")
   # / Waiting for connection on port 21433...
   ```

   ```
   # R session 2
   con <- DBI::dbConnect(..., port=21433)
   DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 1 as n")
   #   n
   # 1 1
   ```

   This connection will stay alive so long as `con` is not closed and the remote end does not close it (e.g., activity timeout).

   Note: I cannot get the `ssh` package to use my ssh-agent, so all passwords must be typed in or otherwise passed in not-ideal ways. There are many ways to not have to type it, such as using the `keyring` package (secure) or envvars, both of which would pass the password to `ssh_connect(..., passwd=<>)`.
3. The above, but using `callr` so that you don't need to *explicit* sessions active (though you will still have another R session.

   ```r
   bgr <- callr::r_bg(function() {
     ssh <- ssh::ssh_connect("r2@remote", passwd=keyring::key_get("r2", "remote"))
     ssh::ssh_tunnel(ssh, port=21433, "otherremote:1433")
   }, supervise = TRUE)
   DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 1 as n")
   #   n
   # 1 1
   ### when your work is done
   bgr$kill()
   ```

   If you do this, I strongly recommend the use of `supervise=TRUE`, which ensures the background R process is killed when *this* (primary) R session exits. This will reduce the risk of having phantom unused R sessions hanging around; in addition to just clogging up the process tree, if one of these phantom R processes is actively forwarding a port, that means nothing else can forward that port. This allows you to continue working, but you are not longer in control of the process doing the forwarding ... and subsequent attempts to tunnel will fail.

   FYI, I generally prefer using `keyring::key_get("r2", "remote")` for password management in situations like this: (1) it prevents me from having to set that envvar each time I start R ... which will inadvertently store the plain-string password in `~/.Rhistory`, if saved; (2) it prevents me from having to set that envvar in the global environment permanently, which is prone to other stupid mistakes I make; and (3) is much better protected since it is using the native credentials of your base OS. Having said that, you can replace the above use of `keyring::key_get(..)` with `Sys.getenv("mypass")` in a pinch, or in a case where the code is running on a headless system where a credentials manager is unavailable.

   And if you want this to be a little more resilient to timeout disconnects, you can instead use

   ```r
   bgr <- callr::r_bg(function() {
     ssh <- ssh::ssh_connect("r2@remote", passwd=keyring::key_get("r2", "remote"))
     while (!inherits(try(ssh::ssh_tunnel(ssh, port=21433, "otherremote:1433"), silent=TRUE), "try-error")) Sys.sleep(1)
   }, supervise = TRUE)
   ```

   which will repeatedly make the tunnel so long as the attempt does not error. You may need to experiment with this to get it "perfect".
4. `callr` is really just using `processx` under the hood to start a background R process and allow you to continue working. If you don't want the "weight" of another R process solely to forward ports, you can use `processx` to start an explicit call to `ssh` that does everything you need it to do.

   ```r
   proc <- processx::process$new("ssh", c("-L", "21433:otherremote:1433", "r2@remote", "-N"))
   ### prompts for password
   DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 1 as n")
   #   n
   # 1 1
   ### when done
   proc$kill()
   # [1] TRUE
   ```