# Identify and close an SSH tunnel from R

Tags: r, ssh

I need to connect in R to a DB that uses an SSH tunnel. Based on googling SO tells me that I [have to create an SSH tunnel first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551095/r-ssh-tunnel-mysql), then connect to my DB, but there is little on how to safely close the tunnel after executing my SQL.

Example:

```
if(!require(RPostgreSQL)) install.packages("RPostgreSQL")

# Create tunnel
myssh<-"ssh -f <server_user>@<server_ip>  -L <unused_local_port>:localhost:<database_remote_port> -N"
system(myssh)

# Connect to DB
drv  <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
conn <- dbConnect(
  drv,
  host = "127.0.0.1", user = "postgres",
  password = "", dbname = "mydb",
)

# How to close tunnel?
```

**How to correctly detect and close the SSH tunnel created by R?**

PS I'm on Windows!

Comment: Steph! Before I go dust off my Windows VM, does `server_user` have the authority to run scripts on the remote (I'm assuming) linux system or just establish a tunnel?

Comment: @hrbrmstr `server_user` can indeed do stuff on the linux box

Comment: maybe the article [Auto-closing SSH tunnels](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/24/auto-closing-ssh-tunnels/) has the solution.

Comment: @bdecaf that is totally the solution. Can you post it as an answer so I can chuck some points your way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a nice article at [Auto-closing SSH tunnels](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/24/auto-closing-ssh-tunnels/) - it suggests using such code to connect:

```
ssh -f -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 me@remote.example.org sleep 10;
```

It uses a feature that ssh will not close a connection while in use. It will first wait 10s - and if there the connection gets used close the connection once it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac and Linux you can close it as any other background ssh connection:

```
ps -ef | grep ssh
```

and then

```
kill -9 pid
```

I dont't know if there is `ps` on windows

Comment: Is that an interactive process or could you extract a pid from the `ps` and pipe it into the `kill`?

Comment: You can always extract the pid from Terminal into R by running `system("ps aux | grep ssh", intern=TRUE)` (it's the first number in the row, i.e., the entry after your computer's username).