# Reading data to R form the remote server via the intermediate server

Tags: r, ssh, remote-server, rcurl

There are two servers A and B.

How can I read the data directly to R.

Note: I can connect to B via A server so this post cannot help:
[Can R read from a file through an ssh connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226867/can-r-read-from-a-file-through-an-ssh-connection)

I need two ssh commands!

Comment: try this: `read.table( pipe( 'ssh hostnameA "ssh hostnameB \'cat data.txt\'"' ), header = T )`

Comment: I get this error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).