# Load file in ssh server with R

Tags: r, ssh

Hel lo,

I have some files that are presrnt into a ssh server that I need to open from my `R local software` .

Does someone know a way `to load these files from the server to the local computer` instead of doing a (copy) scp of this file to my local computer and then load them in `R`.

Thank you for your help

Comment: maybe check out this: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ssh/

Comment: I did not find a way to just read a file to upload a dataframe in a ssh server..

Comment: sorry too fast just now. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226867/can-r-read-from-a-file-through-an-ssh-connection