# How can I list files from a ssh directory in R?

Tags: r, ssh, import, remote-access, remote-server

I know I can read files directly from ssh connections using `pipe` thanks to the the previous questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226867/can-r-read-from-a-file-through-an-ssh-connection?lq=1) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347450/how-do-you-connect-to-a-remote-server-with-ssh-in-r).
However I would like to read all the files with unknown names from such directories, and therefore I would need to use something such `list.files()` first on the ssh directory. Is it possible? How?

Comment: by "all files" you mean recursing into subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ssh` directly using `system2`, specifying `ls` as one of its arguments, and storing its output. E.g.:

```
system2('ssh', args = c('1.2.3.4', 'ls'), stdout = TRUE)
```

Replace `1.2.3.4` with the target machine's IP address or hostname. In the example above, the target user's home folder is listed, but you can add a further argument with the desired path, e.g.:

```
args = c('1.2.3.4', 'ls', '/tmp')
```

`ssh` options, such as a different user or port, can be specified as arguments before the target machine's address, e.g.:

```
args = c('-l', 'other_user',
         '-p', 2222,
         '1.2.3.4',
         'ls', '/tmp')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ssh`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh/index.html) package.

```r
sess <- ssh::ssh_connect("myuser@remoteserver.com:22") # 22 is default, port not required unless different
aa <- ssh::ssh_exec_internal(sess, "ls -l /tmp/")
rawToChar(aa$stdout)
# [1] "total 3488\n-rw-rw-r--   1 myuser         myuser    508 Jan  4 05:38 exp\ndrwxr-xr-x 155 root           root    12288 Sep 12 13:14 quux\ndrwx------   3 root           root     4096 Dec 28 12:30 snap-private-tmp\ndrwx------   2 myuser         myuser   4096 Dec 28 12:34 tmux-1000\n"
```

If you don't care about the file metdata, then use a different command.

```r
ab <- ssh::ssh_exec_internal(sess, "ls /tmp/")
rawToChar(ab$stdout)
# "exp\nquux\nsnap-private-tmp\ntmux-1000"
```

You can generally trust splitting on `"\n"` unless you know some remote filenames might be nefarious/untrusted. If you want to be more secure about it, or if you need more filtering or conditioning than `ls` alone can provide, then you can use `find` and its `-print0`, though `rawToChar` won't work so it requires a little more work.

```r
split(ac$stdout, cumsum(ac$stdout == as.raw(0))) |>
  sapply(function(z) rawToChar(if (z[1] == as.raw(0)) z[-1] else z))
#                       0                       1                       2                       3                       4 
#                 "/tmp/"              "/tmp/exp"             "/tmp/quux"        "/tmp/tmux-1000" "/tmp/snap-private-tmp"
```

We `split` the raw vector based on the presence of `00` (null byte). However, since the first null-byte will be found as the first byte in the second and subsequent list-elements after `split` (not the first list-element), we need to conditionally remove it before converting the remaining raw bytes to a string.

It might be useful to know the arguments for `find` such as `-type f` (not shown) and `-maxdepth 1`. See [`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).